# Calling [UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] is no-ops and it will trigger another pushViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, pushviewcontroller

I am currently working on the following situation, i need to push two viewController (A and B) in sequence in short time.

So this is what i do.

1. First call, `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcA animated:yes]`
2. In `[navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated]`, i call `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:yes]`

Since i have overrides some of functions in `[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated]`, i want `[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated]` only triggered twice, one when pushing `vcA` and one when pushing `vcB`.

However, the current situation is that `[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated]` will be triggered for three times:

1. First time when we call `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcA animated:yes]`
2. Second time when we call `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:yes]`. However, this is strange because at this point, this is not doing anything. I checked `NavigationController.viewControllers` and find that `vcB` did not get pushed
3. Third time, `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:yes]` is triggered again, and it is triggered by `[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]`, the full stacktrace can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIlxe.png)

So my question is, where did the third  `[UINavigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:yes]` come from? I am certain that i did not override any `_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this (not a best practice)

Try this code:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vcA, animated: false)
navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
```